# in this code i want add popup box link but showing one error inside <a >.. help me

Tags: php

```
    if (strlen($string) > 500)
        {
            $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 500);

            $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="#" onclick=\"showAjaxModal('.base_url().'index.php?modal/popup/readmore/' . $row['categories_id'].')\"> ...Read More </a> ' ; 

        }
    echo $string;
?>
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Umm........... there's no js here. There is kind of, but not enough code to support the question.

Comment: Can you post the **rendered** markup?

Comment: `index.php?modal/popup/readmore/....` isn't the right syntax here.

Comment: `'... <a href="#" onclick="showAjaxModal(\'' . base_url() . 'index.php?modal/popup/readmore/' . $row['categories_id'] . '\')"> ...Read More </a> '`

Comment: someone is attempting to remove the javascript tag in an suggestive edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18435203  to which it could be relevant here.

Comment: there should also be accompanied HTML in the question.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue at hand.. https://3v4l.org/lhVsf ( I had to remove `base_href` as 3v4l won't allow it)

Comment: Given the actual problem the OP is trying to solve, how about `text-overflow: ellipsis;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, 500);
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ' '));
$string .= '... <a href="#" onclick="showAjaxModal(\'' . base_url() . 'index.php?modal/popup/readmore/' . $row['categories_id'] . '\')">... Read More</a>';
```

You are missing the single quotes which should wrap the url inside the showAjaxModal function.

Comment: its working ... thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot quotation marks for the URL?

```
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="#" onclick=\"showAjaxModal("'.base_url().'index.php?modal/popup/readmore/' . $row['categories_id'].'")\"> ...Read More </a> ' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, much more manageable version:

```
if (strlen($string) > 500) {
  $cut = substr($string, 0, 500);
  $cut = substr($cut, 0, strrpos($cut, ' '));

  $url = base_url() . "index.php?modal/popup/readmore/" . $row['categories_id'];
  $string = "$cut... <a href='#' onclick='showAjaxModal(\"$url\")'> ...Read More </a>"; 
}
echo $string;
```